# Prevent two connections from reading same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, queue, message-queue

I am looking at building a database based Message Queue implementation. I will essentially have a database table which will contain a autogenerated id (bigint), a message id and message data. I will be writing a pull based consumer which will query for the oldest record (min(id)) from the table and hands it over for processing.

Now my doubt is how would I handle the querying of the oldest record when there are mulitple threads of consumer. How do I lock the first read record to the first consumer and basically not even make it visible to the next one.

One idea that I have is to add another column called locked by where I will store, lets say the thread name and select the record for update and immediately update the locked by column and then continue processing it. So that I will not select the locked columns in the next query.

Is this a workable solution?

**Edit:**
Essentially, this is what I want.

1. Connection one queries the database table for a row. Reads first row and locks it while reading for update.
2. Connection two queries the database table for a row. Should not be able to read the first row, should read second row if available and lock it for update.
3. Similar logic for connection 3, 4, etc..
4. Connection one updates the record with its identifier. Processes it and subsequently deletes the record.

Comment: Maybe you should consider usage of SQL Server Service Broker?

Comment: Thank you.. will look into it.. does the message broker ensure that messages are delivered properly in a multi threaded scenario?

Comment: That works to lock the record, but to ensure only one thread selects the same record, *before* you have managed to update the locked column you pretty much need to either lock the entire table or use `sp_getapplock` to ensure single threaded access.

Comment: Did not understand the logic.
First thread will lock and process the last record, but what will do other threads?
Will they rollback or wait?
What will happen when the first thread finishes?
Will other thread pick it up and re-process?

Comment: @PavanAndhukuri. with Service Broker, messages are delivered in FIFO order within a conversation.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin Updated the question with logic..

Comment: @DanGuzman Can you please cross check the logic and suggest if that can be achieved by Service Broker. I feel with Service broker, once the message is read, it is popped out of the queue. And then if the listener fails to process it, it will be lost.

Comment: @PavanAndhukuri, message loss is a consideration with either a queue table or SB queue as discussed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Connection one queries the database table for a row. Reads first row and locks it while reading for update.
> 2. Connection two queries the database table for a row. Should not be able to read the first row, should read second row if available and
>    lock it for update.
> 3. Similar logic for connection 3, 4, etc..
> 4. Connection one updates the record with its identifier. Processes it and subsequently deletes the record.

TL;DR, see Rusanu's [using tables as queues](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/). The example DDL below is gleaned from the article.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FifoQueueTable (
     Id bigint not null identity(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT pk_FifoQueue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,Payload varbinary(MAX)
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_EnqueueFifoTableMessage
    @payload varbinary(MAX)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.FifoQueueTable (Payload) VALUES (@Payload);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_DequeueFifoTableMessage
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP(1) Payload
    FROM dbo.FifoQueueTable WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    ORDER BY Id
)
DELETE FROM cte
OUTPUT deleted.Payload;
GO
```

This implementation is simple but handing the unhappy path can be complex depending on the nature of the messages and the cause of the error.

When message loss is acceptable, one can simply use the default autocommit transaction and log errors.

In cases where messages must not be lost, the dequeue must be done in a client-initiated transaction and committed only after successful processing or no message read. The transaction will also ensure messages are not lost if the application or database service crashes. A robust error handling strategy depends on the type of error, nature of messages, and message processing order implications.

A poison message (i.e. an error in the payload that prevents the message from ever being successfully), one can insert the bad message into a dead letter table for subsequent manual review and commit the to transaction.

A transient error, such as a failure calling an external service, can be handled with techniques like:

- Rollback the transaction so the message is first in the FIFO queue for retry next iteration.
- Requeue the erred message and commit so the message is last in the FIFO queue for retry.
- Enqueue the erred message in a separate retry queue along with a retry count. The message can be inserted into dead letter table once a retry limit is reached.

The app code can also include retry logic during message processing but should avoid long running database transactions and fallback to one techniques above after some retry threshold.

These same concepts can be implemented with Service Broker to facilitate a T-SQL only solution (internal activation) but adds complexity when that's not a requirement (as in your case). Note that SB queues intrinsically implement the "READPAST" requirement but, because all messages within the same conversation group are locked, the implication is that each message will need to be in a separate conversation.

Comment: really interesting that why so far nobody upvoted it. Nice idea.